# Authenticating the valid session using Spring session management through Ajax call

Tags: ajax, web-services, session, spring-mvc

I have implemented the session management using Spring. I have used session.setAttribute("username", username), the default mechanism of Spring for setting the session after successful login. Now, for the successive Ajax call after login, when I try to check the session using session.getId(), default Spring method, to autheticate the valid user session, I am getting a different session id from different Ajax call. Hence, I am not able to validate the session of that user due to the fact that on each Ajax call I am receiving different session id which is not same as the original session id set during the login. But when I try the same using Advanced Rest Client from Google Chrome, the session seems to be working properly and the successive call after login have the same sesson id. I am not sure if I am missing something important which needs to be taken care of in case of Ajax request.

Below is the Ajax call I have written for communicating with the Spring backend.

```
var doc = {
    'name' : 'abc'
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://example.com:8080/service/fetchdata",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data : JSON.stringify(doc),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("Success : " + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Failed : " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Please help me understand how do I handle session using Ajax call and Spring session management as I am new to Spring MVC. This is important for me to implement. How do I make sure that the session id does not change in the successive Ajax call after successful login or is there any other mechanism to handle the same scenario. Any help would be appreciated.